# bash globstar matching

Tags: bash, wildcards, globstar

I have this directory structure:

```
~/tmp/globstar ɀ  find dir -type f
dir/file.ext
dir/subdir1/file.ext
dir/subdir2/file.ext
```

and, with the `globstar` option enabled in Bash, I can say:

```
~/tmp/globstar ɀ  ls -1 dir/**/*.ext
dir/subdir1/file.ext
dir/subdir2/file.ext
```

My question is: why is `dir/file.ext` excluded from this list?

[Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin-1) says this about `globstar`:

> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

“**zero**” in this paragraph let me with the impression that `dir/file.ext` should have been included; unless I’m hopefully missing something.

Comment: What is this character? `ɀ`?

Comment: What version of bash, on what platform? I can't reproduce this with bash 4.2.37 on Debian wheezy or bash 4.1.5 on Debian squeeze. @slm `unicode ɀ` or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%B1%BF)

Comment: @Gilles Is that a prompt?

Comment: slm, Yes! `ɀ` is just a character used here to distinguish prompt. Some users prefer the character `£` or `€` instead of `$` :). Originally, `ɀ` a 'z' character created for a special African language notation :-)

Comment: Could you please let us know which version of Bash in which system did you use? Please check my reply: I have not found a version of Bash (in recent distributions) where it does not work as you expected.

Comment: "GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)" shipped with OS X 10.9 has this behavior.

Comment: @natevw: The `globstar` option is supported in Bash since the version 4.0. Older versions should show an error when you try to manipulate the option. I have extended my reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that refers to the subdirectory level only. `**` without `/` matches

1. all files and directories
2. zero or more subdirectories

But it does not completely disappear. `**/` means that no files in the highest-level directory which `**` applies to are matched.

You need `dir/*.ext dir/**/*.ext`.

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly my fallback, it just doesn’t look pretty. ;-)

Answer (score 18):

This works as you expected in these versions of Bash as supplied with the listed distributions:

- 4.1.2(1) — CentOS 6.5
- 4.1.5(1) — Debian 6.0.10
- 4.1.10(4) — Cygwin 1.7.31
- 4.2.46(1) — CentOS 7.1
- 4.3.11(1) — Ubuntu 14.04.1
- 4.3.30(1) — Debian 8.1

In fact the versions listed above are all that I tested. In other words I did not find a version 4 of Bash where it does not work. The option `globstar` was added in Bash 4.0 see [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n2184). In older versions the command `shopt -s globstar` should return an error.

### Tests

**1.** `dir/**/*.ext` matches `dir/file.ext`:

```
~/tests$ ls -1 dir/**/*.ext
dir/file.ext
dir/subdir1/file.ext
dir/subdir2/file.ext
```

**2.** `**/*.ext` matches `file.ext`:

```
~/tests$ cd dir
~/tests/dir$ ls -1 **/*.ext
file.ext
subdir1/file.ext
subdir2/file.ext
```

**Preparing the environment** for reproducing the tests above:

```
mkdir -p dir/subdir{1,2}
touch dir/{,subdir{1,2}/}file.ext
shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: this is the right answer. The OP forgot to set `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: Yes, globstar is not set. This answer is right but imho it is not enough. The OP's test is very limited, since it does not test subdir1/subsubdir. So, as Alex028502 said: "With globstar off, ** ends up behaving just like *"

Answer (score 8):

I looks to me like you have/had globstar turned off.  It can be turned on on like this:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Not only will it not match zero subdirectories, but it won't match two subdirectories either:

```
$ find dir -type f #the same as yours except with a directory inside one of the subdirectories
dir/file.ext
dir/subdir1/file.ext
dir/subdir1/subsubdir/file.ext
dir/subdir2/file.ext
$ shopt -u globstar #turn globstar off
$ #will only show files in subdirectories
$ #will not show files in dir or in subsubdir
$ echo dir/**/*.ext
dir/subdir1/file.ext dir/subdir2/file.ext
$ shopt -s globstar #turn globstar on
$ #will show all four files
$ echo dir/**/*.ext
dir/file.ext dir/subdir1/file.ext dir/subdir1/subsubdir/file.ext dir/subdir2/file.ext
```

With globstar off, ** ends up behaving just like *, so `dir/**/*.ext` gets the same result as `dir/*/*.ext`

```
$ echo dir/*/*.ext
dir/subdir1/file.ext dir/subdir2/file.ext
```

which sometimes tricks me into thinking globstar is on

check your current globstar setting like this:

```
shopt | grep globstar
```

Comment: You can check a shell option setting directly, as in `shopt globstar`.